# Appending column to a data frame - R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to append a column to data frame in the following scenario?

```
dfWithData <- data.frame(start=c(1,2,3), end=c(11,22,33))
dfBlank <- data.frame()
```

..how to append column `start` from `dfWithData` to `dfBlank`?

It looks like the data should be added when data frame is being initialized. I can do this:

```
dfBlank <- data.frame(dfWithData[1])
```

but I am more interested if it is possible to append columns to an empty (but inti)

Comment: The more important question is why are you creating an empty data frame and then trying to populate it? The _correct_ solution to this problem will likely avoid that step entirely.

Comment: @joran: I can be wrong. I am just learning R. So, would you suggest doing this at the initialization point? i.e. the second approach

Comment: Probably. But it's hard to say unless you back up a bit and explain why you're doing this.

Comment: @joran: Ok sure. So I am querying the database using RODBC (which returns data frame as result). This data frame contains 4 (say A,b,C and D) columns from the database. I need to extract columns A,B,C and A,B,D columns from the data frame and stick them in different excel files. This is why I create 2 empty data frames and fill respective columns

Comment: Just subset the data frame from the RODBC output: `df[,c('A','B','D')]`, etc.

Comment: @joran: Can you please add the comment as an answer below so that I can mark the question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest simply subsetting the data frame you get back from the RODBC call. Something like:

```
df[,c('A','B','D')]
```

perhaps, or you can also subset the columns you want with their numerical position, i.e.

```
df[,c(1,2,4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dfBlank[1:nrow(dfWithData),"start"] <- dfWithData$start
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. I get the error `Error in "$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*, "start", value = c(1, 2, 3)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 0`

Comment: Whoops, I didn't check my solution. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @darkie15 Edited - you need to specify the row numbers you are changing. Try it now.

Comment: Still does not work !! I don't think you can reference a column that does not exist in first place i.e. `dfBlank$start`

Comment: I think you're right. You'd need to subset with brackets. I've edited again. Echoing joran, normally you don't create empty data frames and fill them with data - you will create them at the point of initialization from functions like `read.csv` or `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks for working on the answer. But I would be choosing joran's suggestion as the final answer to the post.