# Append each data frame iteratively into a larger data frame R + replicate the pivot functionality in Excel

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table

I did search for this and linking to entries [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053090/appending-multiple-files-into-a-data-frame-using-r), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053090/appending-multiple-files-into-a-data-frame-using-r) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162278/appending-column-to-a-data-frame-r).

But they don't answer my question.

Code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(files.df)) {
  Final <- parser(as.character(files.df[i,]))
  Final2 <- rbind(Final2,Final)
}
```

files.df contains over 30 filenames (read from a directory using list.files) which is then passed to a custom function parser which returns a dataframe holding over 100 lines (number varies from one file to the next). Both Final and Final2 are initialised with NA outside the for loop. The script runs fine with rbind but its a semantic issue - the resulting output is not what I expect. The resulting dataframe is a lot smaller than the files combined.

I am certain it has to do with the rbind bit.

Secondly, am looking to mimic the pivot functionality that's in excel, whereby I have four columns, the first column is repeated for each row, second column is distinct, third column is distinct, fourth column is distinct. The final dataframe should be pivoted around the first column. Any idea as to how I can achieve this? I had a go at cast and melt but no avail.

Any thoughts would be great! Would be good if I can stick to the data frame structure.

Attaching pictures for reference:

[image: Before pivot]
[With pivot on and ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha6OK.png)

Comment: there is not too much info, in your questions, but you can try `Final1 <- lapply(as.character(files.df[i,]), parser)`. it will give you a list of data.frames and then you might be able to see exactly where is the problem. later you can just use `Final2 <- do.call(rbind, Final1)` to build the final data.frame

Comment: After a bit more digging, the input xmls had a bit of repetition which explains why when removing for duplicates it didnt add up. Thanks Carlos for the swift reply. But while we are at it, I am looking to mimic the pivot functionality that's in excel, whereby  I have four columns, the first column is repeated for each row, second column is distinct, third column is distinct, fourth column is distinct. The final dataframe should be pivoted around the first column.

Comment: try with the library `reshape2` and the function `dcast`

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34709864/496488) of how to mimic pivot table functionality.

Comment: Thanks - I get the following error when I implement the dcast: In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. I can imagine this would be quite problematic if the dataframes do not have the same number of rows (dataframes created iteratively through a for loop then bound  together by rows rbind rather than cols). Or is this not true?

Comment: Can you post some data, even mock example as pivots an vary by need? For instance, columns can be pivoted values or suffixed with same stem (Day1, Day2, Day3, etc.). And each with different aggregation. Surely, you know Excel pivots can be designed in many ways.

Comment: Appreciate feedback - amended this in the initial question.

Comment: Not nice to downvote me - I'm new to the forum so would appreciate some constructive feedback. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

For your pivot functionality which essentially requires transforming dataframe from long to wide format, aggregating on the `Value` column, you can use base R's [reshape()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/reshape):

```
reshapedf <- reshape(df, v.names = c("Value"),
                     timevar=c("Identifier"),
                     idvar = c("Date"), 
                     direction = "wide")
# RENAME COLUMNS
names(reshapedf) <- c('Date', 'A', 'B', 'C')
# CONVERT NAs TO ZEROS
reshapedf[,c(2:4)] <- data.frame(sapply(reshapedf[,c(2:4)], 
                                        function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)))
# RESET ROW.NAMES
row.names(reshapedf) <- 1:nrow(reshapedf)
```

Alternatively, the dedicated package, [reshape2](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/reshape2/docs/cast) which as seen below tends to be less wordy and less post-formatting. Hence, most prefer this transformation route. Plus, like Excel Pivot Tables other aggregate functions are available (sum, mean, length, etc.):

```
library(reshape2)
reshape2df <- dcast(df, Date~Identifier, sum, value.var="Value")
```